# Enviar valor de DropDown para Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp

Como eu faço para enviar um valor de um Drop Down para um [*IFRAME*]?

Estou recuperando o valor assim:

```
function mandaIframe() {
    pai = parent.document.form1; // especifica o elemento de id="formularioX", dentro do documento que é pai da página.
    var idcat = pai.varField_idcat.value; // captura o valor do campo de id="numero", dentro do elemento de id="formularioX", dentro do documento que é pai.
}
```

Porém  estou tendo problemas para mandar para o Iframe.

Comment: Sim é. Ele esta logo abaixo de um DropDown

Comment: Na mesma página. O DropDowm acima e o Iframe mais abaixo. 
Quero pegar o valor do DropDown e mandar para a página que esta no SRC do IFRAME

Comment: Sim é do Mesmo.

Comment: Sim estou usando ASP Classico.

Comment: A partir da página pai. O Código que eu mandei é apenas para pegar o valor do combo.
Agora preciso jogar para o iFrame.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode alterar o `src` do `iframe` pegando o valor selecionado no dropdown e passando esse valor como parâmetro na URL do `iframe`:

```
function mandaIframe() {
   var idcat = document.querySelector("#numero").value; // valor selecionado no dropdown
   document.querySelector("iframe").src = "pagina.asp?id="+idcat; // alterar o src do iframe
}
```

No `iframe` você pega o valor via ASP com `request`:

```
<%
idcat = request("id");
%>
```

Com a variável `idcat` recebendo o valor de `id` na URL, você faz o que desejar.

Answer (score 0):

me maneira geral, o ideal que a comunicação entre documentos distintos seja feita utilizando troca de mensagens.

Vamos pegar o seguinte caso de uso, a pagina deve enviar um texto (`value` da `textarea`) para o `iFrame`, o `iFrame` deve atualizar o seu conteúdo tendo como base o texto recebido, então deve notificar a pagina pai para que ela limpe a `textarea`.

para alcançar tal resultado, você pode fazer uso do `window.postMessage(...)` e do `window.addEventListener('message', function (evt) { ... })`

```js
// html/script do iFrame
var html = `
<html>
  <head><\/head>
  <body>
    <div id="box">
      
    <\/div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      var box = document.getElementById('box');
      window.addEventListener('message', function (evt) {
        if (evt.origin !== 'null') // modifique o 'null' para a dominio do iframe.
          return;
        box.textContent = evt.data
        window.parent.postMessage('OK', '*') // modifique o '*' para a dominio da pagina pai.
      })
    <\/script>
  <\/body>
<\/html>
`;

// criando a pagina a ser carregada no iFrame.
var blob = new Blob([html], { type: 'text/html' })
document.querySelector('iframe').src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)

var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe')
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea')
var button = document.querySelector('button')

// enviando uma mensagem para o iframe
button.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
  iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(textarea.value, '*') // modifique o '*' para a dominio do iframe.
})

// recebendo uma mensagem do iframe
window.addEventListener('message', function (evt) {
  if (evt.origin !== 'null' || evt.data !== 'OK')  // modifique o 'null' para a dominio da pagina.
    return;
  textarea.value = '';
})
```

```css
textarea, iframe {
  width: 300px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <iframe src='#'></iframe>
</div>
<div><button>Copiar</button></div>
```

Comment: @Carmona007 o código acima tanto envia mensagens para o iFrame como recebe do mesmo.